# Trigger warning on page close but not on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that refresh automatically every so often using the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" >
```

However, I want the page to give out a warning if the user decides to close the browser tab asking to confirm if they really want to quit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ myUnloadEvent(); }
function myUnloadEvent() {
alert ('Are you sure you really want to exit?');
}
</script>
```

However, this trigger an alert on the refresh asking if you really want to refresh as well.

Is there a way I can trigger the message only on browser tab close and not refresh?

Thanks

Comment: What if you use js to refresh the page instead, using same function for alert or refresh? you just need some param to show the function what event calls it.

Comment: Use a Javascript-function to set the refresh instead of Meta-refresh

Comment: Sounds like an idea. I will give that a go and see how it goes.